# Error on RTP/RTSP streaming on Android

Tags: java, android, streaming, rtsp, rtp

I'm building a streaming app that relies on MediaPlayer to play video streamed via RTP/RTSP (using VLC Media Player as the server).

This is the code for the activity in question:

```
public class MediaPlayerActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener  {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SurfaceHolder vidHolder;
private SurfaceView surfaceVideo;
private String address;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_player);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
    address=b.getString("EXTRA_ADDRESS");
    surfaceVideo =(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceVideo);
    vidHolder = surfaceVideo.getHolder();
    vidHolder.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(address));
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    mediaPlayer.release();
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

As you can see, the activity gets the URL of the stream  from other activity. When I start the app to receive the stream via **RTP** I get the following output on logcat:

```
09-28 17:50:44.000    1223-1223/com.example.cosmickone.mystreamingapp E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ android_media_MediaPlayer_setDataSourceAndHeaders : start showDialog  drm_status = -1
09-28 17:50:44.000    1223-1223/com.example.cosmickone.mystreamingapp E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ android_media_MediaPlayer_setDataSourceAndHeaders : end showDialog
09-28 17:50:44.270    1223-1240/com.example.cosmickone.mystreamingapp E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -1003)
09-28 17:50:44.290    1223-1223/com.example.cosmickone.mystreamingapp E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-1003)
```

And when I wanna open the **RTSP** stream this is the error shown on logcat:

```
09-28 17:49:25.370    1223-1223/com.example.cosmickone.mystreamingapp E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ android_media_MediaPlayer_setDataSourceAndHeaders : start showDialog  drm_status = -1
09-28 17:49:25.370    1223-1223/com.example.cosmickone.mystreamingapp E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ android_media_MediaPlayer_setDataSourceAndHeaders : end showDialog
09-28 17:49:25.370    1223-1239/com.example.cosmickone.mystreamingapp E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
09-28 17:49:25.410    1223-1223/com.example.cosmickone.mystreamingapp E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
```

I've succesfuly received the streams on VLC clients both on Windows and Android, and I'm trying with a variety of files from different formats, so I would discard this is because of media codecs or wrong server setup. I'm testing it on my local network so there shouldn't be a problem with ports/firewall, am I wrong?

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I have the INTERNET permission on my manifest already.